# MySQL - How can I import a table when rows have the same primary key?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to combine the data from two sites that are identical aside from their data (one is a blog another the main site). If I export then import the table a couple thousand entries have the same primary key. The key, to my knowledge isn't used anywhere so I don't mind if they change. I just want the data I'm importing to be added at the end of the current table and the primary key updated.

Comment: Can you post table structure? (`SHOW CREATE TABLE ...`)

Comment: If I try to open the sql file in an editor it will drag my system down. It's pretty big.

Comment: Can you connect to mysql after first part import and run `show create table ...` command? You should know table name from duplicated key error message.

Comment: i would import to a temporary table, and then run an insert statement without the primary key